# How do you empty clean and disinfectant an aquarium that contain sick fish?

Tags: fish

Just wondering how to properly clean and disinfectant a tank that has had sick fish in it?
Kinda failing at fish keeping.. but I didn't want to give up, I kept researching medice water changes- the lot, but I went away for 4 days and things got bad... 2 fish have died and I have 1 giant pregnant, lonely, just recovering from fin rot, stressed out girl in a tank that may contain bad sickness, how do I clean and disinfectant the whole tank, from gravel to ornaments to heaters nets symphon- everything?
Please help- I'm about ready to give up fish and go back to horses.

Comment: You need to tell us more as to why the fish died.  Mostly fish die due to lack of clean ammonia free water.

Comment: Different reasons- but all comes down to the ph and the water was really bad... fin rot/ cotton like  fungal growth and the other two I don't know... I managed to treat the fin rot but she must of died while I was at school today.. She seemed ok this morning too...

Comment: Also- is their any possibility of saving her babies( she was the one that was pregnant and died today)

Comment: fish lay eggs. Unless there's a male to fertilize them, there's no babies.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/whats-the-best-way-to-clean-a-contaminated-aquarium

Comment: It's sounds like I'm a horrible fish keeper- but like I said the water quality was poor.. and then my guppie got fin rot and all I could do was raise the temp a little and add medicine, because I was going away, then I came back and she was swimming around and looked a tone better.. only to realise that over the few days I was gone before that the other guppie had produced a cotton like growth on her side... I put some medication in the tank and got up the next morning and she was dead..

Comment: Everyone has fish deaths when they start

Comment: Don't concentrate on the deaths. It's unfortunate, yes, but as Graham Chiu points out, it happens to everyone. Instead, concentrate on understanding what happened and becoming a better fish keeper. Make sure you do your reading and improve your knowledge and the whole thing will be much more rewarding.